# Let W be the subspace of all polynomials $p(x)$ in V such that $p (0) =p (1)=p (-1)= 0$ . What is the dimension of W?

Tags: linear-algebra

$W=\left\{ p(x)\in { P }_{ 3 }(x)|P(0)=P(1)=P(-1)=0 \right\} $

how $p(x)\in { P }_{ 3 }(x)$ then

$p(x)={a}_{3}x^3+{a}_{2}x^2+{a}_{1}x+{a}_{0}$

it turns out that

$p(0)={a}_{0}=0$

$p(1)={a}_{0}+{a}_{1}+{a}_{2}+{a}_{3}=0$

$p(-1)={a}_{0}-{a}_{1}+{a}_{2}-{a}_{3}=0$

how ${a}_{0}=0$ we have

$p(1)+p(-1)=2{a}_{2}=0$ where we get ${a}_{2}=0$

substituting ${a}_{0}={a}_{2}=0$ in $p(1)$ or $p(-1)$ and we get ${a}_{1}=-{a}_{3}$

Thus $p(x)={a}_{1}x-{a}_{1}x^3={a}_{1}(x-x^3)$

let's call ${p}_{1}(x)=x-x^3$ then ${p}_{1}(x)\in W$ and thus $p(x)$ is a linear combination of ${p}_{1}(x)$

Now let's show that ${p}_{1}(x)$ is linearly independent. We have to

$\alpha{p}_{1}(x)=\alpha(x-x^3)=\alpha(x)-\alpha(x^3)=0$ where we have to $\alpha=0$.

Thus ${p}_{1}(x)$ is linearly independent. Therefore $\left\{ { p }_{ 1 }(x) \right\}$ is base for W.

So the dimension of W is 1. Is my procedure correct?

Comment: Your proof sounds good. As to the linear independence, it suffices to notice that $x - x^{3} \neq 0$.